# How to use slack api methods in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, botkit

Having troubles to get my head around slack apps with node.js. I am using the Starter Botkit ([Howdy](https://www.botkit.ai/)), hosted on glitch ([glitch.com](https://glitch.com/))

What I have so far works perfectly, it starts a convo with the user, asks a few questions, one after another and ends with a summary including all answers the user gave to the bot.

```
module.exports = function(controller) {

 controller.hears(['reminder'], 'direct_message', function(bot, message) {

 bot.startConversation(message, function(err, convo) {
   convo.say('Ok, let me help you with that ...');

   // Ask Target
   convo.ask('Who should I remind ?', function(response, convo) {

    convo.setVar('target', response.text);
    convo.next();

   });

   // Ask About
   convo.ask('About what ?', function(response, convo) {

    convo.setVar('about', response.text);
    convo.next();

   });

   // Ask Date
   convo.ask('Date ?', function(response, convo) {

    convo.setVar('date', response.text);
    convo.next();

   });

   // Ask Time
   convo.ask('And what time ?', function(response, convo) {

    convo.setVar('time', response.text);
    convo.next();

   });

   convo.say('Got it, I should remind {{vars.target}} : {{vars.about}} on {{vars.date}} at {{vars.time}}');
   convo.next();

  });
 });
};
```

Now I want to make more use of all the [methods](https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add) Slack is providing through the API, for example the `reminders.add` method. I can't find any starting point in **writing a function that uses this method**. Or how to include it in the code above. I am on beginner level of knowledge, please be patient with me :)

For what I understand, all the Oauth process is already taken care of within the botkit files (just need to provide all the keys, and install the app in my team)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the BotKit docs for you and found that they show an example where you simply access the Slack api via the `api` property on the bot object.

https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/readme-slack.md#working-with-slack-integrations

```
bot.api.channels.list({},function(err,response) {
  //Do something...
})
```

Comment: My hero ! Thanks <3